# Rellenar array multidimensional

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional

Siguiendo con el tema de los array multidimensionales, he planteado un ejercicio sencillo.
Una tabla de 3x3 en la que los numeros queden de la siguiente forma:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public class Ejer1 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int numeros[][] = new int[3][3];
        int numeros[][] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numeros[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(numeros[i][j]);
                
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta o tu duda? Porqué no has continuado con la pregunta que ya habías publicado antes, si es que tenías más dudas?

Answer (score -2):

Vale me acabo de dar cuenta de que estoy definiendo un array 3x3 y luego le estoy basicamente diciendo lo mismo, simplemente suprimo la línea donde declaro el array y listo.
El codigo queda de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Ejer1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numeros[][] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numeros[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(numeros[i][j]);

            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Te respondes a tu mismo una pregunta que no has hecho?